# PHP - Find the closest RGB to predefined RGB from list

Tags: php, comparison, pixel, rgb

My goal is to find the closest match of **RGB** compared to the **RGB** from the array. I have already created a function that loops trough every pixel in a picture. The only thing I need now is to **find closest color of each pixel in the picture to the color from the array.**

```
$colors = array(
    array(221,221,221),
    array(219,125,62),
    array(179,80,188),
    array(107,138,201),
    array(177,166,39),
    array(65,174,56),
    array(208,132,153),
    array(64,64,64),
    array(154,161,161),
    array(46,110,137),
    array(126,61,181),
    array(46,56,141),
    array(79,50,31),
    array(53,70,27),
    array(150,52,48),
    array(25,22,22)
);
```

I tried converting picture to 8bits to reduce number of colors and compare them later in database but that just doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: sum the arrays and compare the smallest absolute difference?

Comment: What [_distance metric_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1767967/1553481) would you like to use? Absolute difference, squared absolute difference, or perhaps a perceptional metric?

Comment: Do you have identified a suitable perceptional metric already?

Comment: I have defined over 800 different RGB values in mySQL.

Comment: If you have that many colors, the differences with different metrics are probably minute. Did you try the code below?

Comment: Yeah I've tried it althought It doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$inputColor = array(20,40,80);

function compareColors($colorA, $colorB) {
    return abs($colorA[0] - $colorB[0]) + abs($colorA[1] - $colorB[1]) + abs($colorA[2] - $colorB[2]);
}

$selectedColor = $colors[0];
$deviation = PHP_INT_MAX;

foreach ($colors as $color) {
    $curDev = compareColors($inputColor, $color);
    if ($curDev < $deviation) {
        $deviation = $curDev;
        $selectedColor = $color;
    }
}

var_dump($selectedColor);
```

The advantage of this solution is that you can easily replace the comparison function. It might also be possible to use

**Disclaimer:** There might be more elegant ways of implementation, perhaps leveraging `map`.

Comment: Your function doesn't seem to work properly. I'm not sure maybe I need to sort my colors somehow ?

Comment: Sorting is certainly not necessary. What's the problem?

Comment: I set the inputColor to array(20,22,22) and the given result is 221,221,221 although it should be 25,22,22. Which is much closer.

Comment: Your code seems to be working properly right now. Many thanks !

Comment: Thanks, and you're welcome. Note that you can always tweak the `compareColors` function if you're unhappy with the results.

Comment: There will be no need to tweak it. It works perfectly, just what I needed !

Comment: What a legend! Life saver!